# localStorage.setItem не срабатывает для url

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Друзья, создаю возможность для пользователя установить фон с сохранением для следующих сессий. Почему-то url не сохраняется 
(Опция "Морская волна")

```
else if ($(this).val() == 2)    
{      
  $('body').css('background', 'url(http://www.clipart.net.ua/images/clip9100.jpg)');
  localStorage.setItem('background', 'http://www.clipart.net.ua/images/clip9100.jpg');    
}
```

Заранее спасибо

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/tx4e57xa/4/

Полный код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var getColour;
  if (localStorage.getItem('background') !== null) {
    getColour = localStorage.background;
    $('body').css('background-color', getColour);
  }

  $("#seltag").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
      $('body').css('background', 'red');
      localStorage.setItem('background', 'red');
    } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
      $('body').css('background', 'url(http://www.clipart.net.ua/images/clip9100.jpg)');
      localStorage.setItem('background', 'http://www.clipart.net.ua/images/clip9100.jpg');
    } else {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'blue');
      localStorage.setItem('background', 'blue');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="seltag" onchange="">
<option VALUE="0">Выберете подходящий фон</option>
        <option value="1">Красный</option>
        <option VALUE="2">Морская волна</option>
        <option VALUE="3">Синий</option>
        <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не работает?

Comment: Все сохраняет..

Comment: Нажимаете опцию "Морская волна", перезагружаете страницу - сбрасывается. В остальными такого нет.

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вопросов:

1. При загрузке присваивается `background-color`, а не `image`.
2. Сохраняется в localStorage только url, но для установки в коде ты используешь следующую строку `.css('background', 'url(http://www.clipart.net.ua/images/clip9100.jpg)')`

Если это все исправить, то все заработает. В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var getColour;
  if (localStorage.getItem('background') !== null) {
    getColour = localStorage.background;
    $('body').css('background', getColour);
  }

  $("#seltag").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
      $('body').css('background', 'red');
      localStorage.setItem('background', 'red');
    } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
      $('body').css('background', 'url(http://www.clipart.net.ua/images/clip9100.jpg)');
      localStorage.setItem('background', 'url(http://www.clipart.net.ua/images/clip9100.jpg)');
    } else {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'blue');
      localStorage.setItem('background', 'blue');
    }
  });
});
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tx4e57xa/5/)

Comment: Grundy, огромнейшее спасибо, в тч за пояснения :)